# Nested Scrolling with ScrollView and Widgets in ViewPager

Tags: android, android-widget, android-scrollview

i'm trying to code a custom Launcher for Android. I want to avoid Pages for Widgets. Instead a ScrollView should do the trick. (see the image)

My problem occurs when there is a scrollable Widget on the screen. Instead of scrolling the contents of the widget it just scrolls the ScrollView. So, in this case, the NestedScrollView does not work.

I'm curious about a solution for that problem. I could deliver code when needed.

What I also tried was requesting to disallow the intercept touch event for the scrollview when a widget receives the onTouch Event. However, the onTouch-Event is not fired all the time, I touch a widget.

EDIT: I checked again and it really seems that onClick and onTouch Events are just fired in some Widgets. For example the Google News Widget recognizes neither onClick nor onTouch in my ScrollView. When it's not embedded in the ScrollView however, it works.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out. What I had to do was to create a Subclass of the AppWidgetHostView (like in the stock Android Launcher) and override the onInterceptTouchEvent-Method. There I either return true or false and call the getParent().requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent()-Method when needed.

Comment: I also never succeeded implementing this correctly.